# Clustered indexes, mysql and Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm helping with a Rails application, the intent is for that application to be multi-tenanted.  What this means is that there will be data from multiple users/organisations in the database tables, and often the access path will be along the lines of "get me all the data for my organisation".

We're using MYSQL as the database.

Rails by default creates a primary key on the table using the id column.  The id column is auto-incremented.  This is nice in some ways - rows are always added at the end of the table.  However, consider the following situation:

- An object called foo.  A foo has an id, and always has an
  organisation_id
- Over time each organisation creates foos in the database, these foos
  are interleaved throughout the table (they are stored in id sequence)
- A use case that involves listing all foos for this organisation

The problem I have is that the foos for an organisation are not located closely together in the database, in fact they're spread around very sub-optimally.  Ideally I'd create a primary key of (organisation_id, id) on the table, which would result in all foos for a given organisation being side by side in the table.

Unfortunately, when I do this Rails gives me an 'Unknown primary key for table foos in model Foo' error.  I think I could deal with this by using the composite keys gem to rails, but it seems like there should be some way to make this transparent at the database level.

Is there an alternate approach?

For reference, the command on the database to change my index was:

ALTER TABLE foos ADD KEY (id);    # needed because the id column is auto-increment

ALTER TABLE foos DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(organisation_id, id);

EDIT 1: A blog post that indicates success doing exactly this with composite_primary_keys gem.  Which gives me a bit more confidence with that approach, problem is that it's from 2008, so things may have moved on.  http://www.joehruska.com/?p=6

EDIT 2: Another option I was considering was partitioning instead - the number of organisations probably wouldn't exceed the maximum partitions, and I could probably group them a bit without losing too much benefit.  Unfortunately, the key quote is *every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression. (This also includes the table's primary key* - from the MYSQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html.

So I'm still back needing a composite primary key again.  I'm a little surprised that Rails cares so much about the primary key, rather than simply that a key is present.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how composite_primary_keys not transparent at the database level and how does it relate to the `alter table` thing?

Comment: sorry, I mean the other way round.  I'd like something that is transparent to the Rails app, rather than looking for something that is transparent to the database.  My usual aim when tuning for performance at the database level is to make changes that the application layer is unaware of - adding indexes, changing optimiser parameters.  I found a blog post that indicates success with the composite_primary_keys gem (which I'll add above), but I'd still prefer to avoid the potential change I'll get to my app by moving to composite_primary_keys - arguably it could break upgrades (to rails 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use composite_primary_keys then you may be stuck just relying on a standard index on `:organisation_id` or `[:organisation_id, :id]`
My understanding is that Rails cares about PrimaryKeys so much because of the assumptions is makes with relationships between models. Perhaps it should be improved, you could always suggest it as a future feature.

Comment: I understand that it cares about the id being auto-incremented and unique, I'm just not clear why it minds that it be the primary key.  My main concern is that a standard index will still give me a lot of IO and random reads on my database, where a clustering index would avoid that.  But I'm also seeing that Postgres doesn't really even support clustered indexes, so maybe I'm being paranoid about nothing.

Comment: ah yeah, your initial question said mysql, hence my reply. I totally understand your concern but unless you want to set up horizontal partitioning on organisation_id (not great unless you have just a few) i'd leave it. I don't know how big the data is, but i've worked on large stuff and wouldn't be too concerned with this.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer.  Rails isn't too fussy about databases, so another option was changing to Postgres.  But postgres doesn't support clustered indexes at all, so clearly they don't feel this to be a problem.  A sample case I created loads about 3 million rows into the foo table, split across 1,000 organisations.  I loaded them round robin, so the foos are spread all over the database.  Clustered by id it takes 10 seconds to query all foos for an org (on my low spec server), clustered by org_id, id it takes 300ms.  Next question is if I'll have 3 million records.

Comment: If you are looking at a couple of millions of records, I'd say leave it, coz usually it'll easily fit into the memory. Decent schema & index design & avoid crazy SQL is basically all it takes to deal with that size of data.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm sort of disappointed, in my day job I have an (Oracle) database that has exactly this optimisation problem, and it's a pain in production.  I told myself I wouldn't do the same.  But the size of my app should be a lot less.  Ah well.

Comment: OK, having looked more closely, it uses the key to determine things like "Foo.last", and that's what causes the breakage when it doesn't recognise the key.  I think it would be possible to create a Gem that deals with this behaviour with much less intrusion that composite_keys, and I may do this when I have some time.  I'm imagining something that overrides the Arel behaviour so that it assumes :id is the key if it cannot resolve the key.  I've marked this answer as correct because I haven't found any other way.